# Sorting and limiting data from multiple sources

Tags: database, sorting, aggregate

Having more than one datasource how can select top X latest records from these sources?

Exampe: I have blogposts, comments, forumposts which are stored in different tables (and could be stored in different databases). I need to print out latest 'records' added to the site

Answer (score 1):

If they are in one database, you're probably looking for an SQL union statement.

If they are in different databases, you're probably looking at a programmatic solution.